# search and replace in php template files

Tags: php, regex

Basically trying to convert my whole zend framework website into multilingual.
Initially there was no plan for it and view code was written without using a single wrapper function which we could use at the juncture.  View code in all of the phtml files in my zf project looks like below:

```
<div class="contact">
  <span class="edit">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">edit</a></span>
    <h2>Job Board Info</h2>
    <div class="info-grid">
      <div class="field">Contact Name: </div>
      <div class="field-info">
           <?php echo "Good Guy";?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info-grid">
     <div class="field">Description: </div>
     <div class="field-info">
      <?php echo "He is a very good guy";?>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to search all phtml files for the texts like 
**edit**, **Contact Name**, **Good Guy**, **Description**, **He is avery good guy** 
and replace them with

```
<? echo translate("edit") ?>
<? echo translate("Contact Name") ?>
translate("Good Guy");
<? echo translate("Description") ?>
translate("He is avery good guy");
```

I can perform *regex search and replace* in all phtml files using **Zend Studio** but I am not sure what would be the right regex pattern in order to achieve this. Above texts are not fixed in all tenmplates but is and example only. The regex should skip all html code and find out texts only and replace them with . if any text being echoed like **echo "text"** should be replaced with **translate("text").**

Or please suggest some other way in order to achieve this as fast as possible.

Comment: "for the texts like" ... i assume you want it for "All" texts, not just the given examples - thats not possible, you will end up replacing way to much. You need to do it manually.

Comment: You should write a parser to achieve it. It cannot be done with just regular expressions

Comment: There should be some way to achieve this as I mentioned in last line of my question, hope will get something here

Comment: Small or big, posibility is always there. The following regex pattern seems working in ZendStudo's inbuilt file search and replace mechanism. To search: >([A-Za-z0-9:, ]+)<  Replace with: ><? echo translate("$1") ?><  same could be achieved for php code also will try it too

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is use for example [TextCrawler](http://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/textcrawler.html) (for search&replace multiple files at once) and simply turn

- `>edit<`
- `>contact name: <`
- `>Description: <`

with *case-sensitivity* **off** into

- `><?php echo translate("edit"); ?><`
- `><?php echo translate("Contact Name"); ?><`
- `><?php echo translate("Description"); ?><`

(this depends on how many groups of words you want to translate. this is the manual way.
If you have a bambillion of different things to 'process' like this you may want to use regex for this as well)

..and as for the already PHPfied text in *echos* use indeed regex:

**search for** `(.*)<.*echo.*["\'](.*)["\'].*>` (you may want to be a bit more specific, as this can make alot of false positives - make sure it's suited for the content of the files you want to specifically 'process')

**and replace with** `$1<?php echo translate("$2"); ?>`

..where **$1** (first parentheses in the 'search for' condition) stands for whitespaces on the line or whatever (trying to keep the indentation) and **$2** (second parentheses) stands for the originally echoed string.
It also takes both `"`s and `'`s as correct quotation for echoed text.

And for the love of science:

### BACKUP all your code!

..before you do things like this :D